# Godot: Text on mesh surface

Tags: godot, gdscript

I want to add text on the surface of a mesh. Is there a simple way to do that through GDScript? The mesh could be a built in mesh object or an imported one (from blender for example).

Comment: It is not exactly easy in Godot 3.x, but we can do it. Godot 4.0 has 3D labels, decals, and can generate meshes from text. I'm not sure which of those you are trying to do. The more general the solution, it will take more work. Thus, please narrow the problem to your use case so I can come up with a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Theraot Thank you! I did not know about 3D labels in Godot 4.0. Will try that. Right now I am using Godot 3. So looking for a solution in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean text on a 3d mesh, here's how to do it:

1. Add a Sprite3D
2. Add a Viewport (plain) as a child of your Sprite3D
3. Add a Label as a child of your Viewport
4. Type the text you want to display into text, in the label
5. Attach a script to the Viewport
6. Put this inside:

   tool

   extends Viewport

   func _process(_delta):

   ```
   size = $Label.rect_size
   ```

(Sorry about this code, it's not all fitting into one code, so just type it out)

7. Go into the properties of the Viewport, and go under the section: Render Target
8. Turn V Flip on
9. (OPTIONAL) If you want to make the background transparent, turn Transparent on (near the top of Viewport)
10. Now, go into Sprite3D, and add a texture (New ViewportTexture)
11. Select the viewport which is a child of Sprite3D
12. Now save and reload your scene

If you want to increase the size, you have to follow these steps:

1. Go to the Label -> Theme Overrides -> Fonts -> New DynamicFont -> Settings -> Size.
2. If you change the size, it changes the font size.
3. To actually display a font, you need to go to Font -> Load
4. Now select a ttf file (font file)
5. This will give you any font which you put in, as a ttf file. (Google fonts is a great source to find ttf files)

Hopefully this works for you, if it doesn't tell me, and I will try fixing it!

Comment: If you make the `Viewport` a child of the node that uses its `Texture`, then when the game starts it will cause an error because it tries to load the texture before the `Viewport` has been added to scene tree. To be clear: exported properties are set before children nodes are parented.

Comment: @FluffyPancakes1 Thanks for your solution. There are a couple of issues with this. 1) The label is not shown on the surface of a mesh that's imported from blender 2) in case of the Godot built-in meshes the text displayed is blurry and pixelated. Do you know how to fix this?